# Text to hash with perl

Tags: perl

Is there anyone to help me with Perl? I am new. The problem is that I have the following type of file:

```
37    0.61    61    0.30    86  0.03
61    0.50    42    0.44    65  0.01
```

and I need to sort them like below:

```
86    0.03    61    0.30    37  0.61        
65    0.01    61    0.50    42  0.44
```

and finally have them like:

```
0.03        0.30        0.61        
0.01        0.50        0.44
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: You need to explain more. There are twelve fields, and you want six of them, three + three, on two consecutive lines, is that correct? What are the criteria for selecting the wanted fields? Position in the original string, or value?

Comment: Is the intermediate result (the second group) important, or are you just interested in the last result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert this data

```
37    0.61    61    0.30    86  0.03
61    0.50    42    0.44    65  0.01
```

to this

```
0.03        0.30        0.61        
0.01        0.50        0.44
```

by sorting each pair of numbers by the first value in descending order:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

open my $fh, '<', './input.txt' or die "open: $!\n";

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    my %data;
    while ($line =~ /(\S+)\s+(\S+)/g) {
        $data{$1} = $2;
    }

    foreach my $key (sort {$b <=> $a} keys %data) {
        print "$data{$key}\t";
    }
    print "\n";
}

close $fh;
```

Comment: `chomp $line; my %data = split /\s+/, $line;` could be an "alternative" way to load the hash.

Comment: @Chris Don't use `/\s+/` as regex pattern with `split` when you really mean `' '` (the default value).

Comment: @TLP, thank you for this information, I wasn't aware that the default or ' ' is treated like /\s+/.

Comment: You're welcome. Its not exactly like it, `' '` strips leading whitespace. Sometimes you want that, sometimes not.

Comment: Perhaps you aren't printing to the filehandle i.e. `print $outputfh "\n";`.

Answer (score 0):

Based off of grebneke's solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => qw/all/;

$\ = $/;
$, = "\t";

while (<DATA>)
{
    chomp;
    my %data = split;
    print map $data{$_}, sort {$b <=> $a} keys %data;
}

__DATA__
37    0.61    61    0.30    86  0.03
61    0.50    42    0.44    65  0.01
```